# Anyone know a mousehover trick/alternative which triggers when scrolling with keyboard

Tags: javascript, mouse, hover

Is there an alternative method or a trick to the hover method which can trigger a function when the cursor moves from one div to another as the user scrolls the page.

I have **sort of** got it working using some javascript (jQuery) on the hover event of the current post div. However, I've noticed the hover event only triggers when the mouse is actually moved. If the page is scrolled using the keyboard (page) up/down it does not trigger.

(I can note that soup.io for instance has found a way to get this working, but I can't find how they do it)

Comment: I don't see it working on soup.io in Firefox. What browser are you using and what behavior do you see?

Comment: Sorry, I could have been clearer I see. Here's some additional info. What I am going for is this: On a blog (davur.net) I display the comments next to every post, but I have it faded to .30 opacity. But for the current post I wish for the comments to fade in to 1.00 opacity. This is currently implemented using the hover event. But does not trigger on keyboard scrolling.

My comparison to soup.io is that they have a [ # | repost | react | share ] which is hidden initially but shows only on the current post. This does trigger on both hover and keyboard scrolling.

Comment: The soup.io trick (however they do it) triggers on keyboard scrolling on Firefox 3.0, Safari 4, Chrome, IE8 (although not consistently), Opera 9.64 (although with a slight delay).

My hover approach works with Firefox and Opera but not with Chrome, IE or Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's quite complicated; you can no longer rely on the **`onMouseOver`** event - the only event that triggers when a page is scrolled is **`onScroll`**. The steps involved:

1. Go through elements, storing each of their widths, heights and offsets (distance from left/top of screen) in an array.
2. When the onScroll event is triggered check the last known position of the cursor against all chosen elements (go through the array) - if the cursor resides over one of the elements then call the handler.

Quick (unreliable) prototype: http://pastie.org/507589

Comment: I like this idea. I personally would only need heights and y offsets as the divs / posts are listed vertically. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sample? I'm guessing that the layout of the elements on the page are blocking the *mouseover* event. My simple example below works as you described it should. With the cursor at the top of the page and using keyboard navigation, the *mouseover* events are fired.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function log(text)
{
    document.getElementById('logger').value += text + "\n";
}
</script>

<div id="div1" style="background: yellow; height: 100px;margin-top: 100px" onmouseover="log('mouseover div1');">
div1
</div>
<textarea id="logger" cols="60" rows="12" style="float:right;"></textarea>
<div id="div2" style="background: red; height: 1000px" onmouseover="log('mouseover div2');">
div2
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is similar to what I already have. It does not work on keyboard scrolling on Chrome, IE or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the mousewheel event.

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').onmousewheel = function() {
  alert('You win!');
  alert('Seriously! It's just like that');
};
```

I only tested this in Chrome (webkit)